# Undo operation in Xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

Does Xlwings have an undo operation?

I have searched the documentation and cannot find anything.

```py
import xlwings as xw

wb_name = "my_wb.xlsx"
app = xw.App(visible=True)
wb: xw.Book = app.books.open(wb_name )
sh: xw.Sheet = wb.sheets[0]
sh.range("A1").value = 1
# undo here
xw.apps.active.quit()
```

I know I can manually implement an undo above by capturing the previous cell contents and reapplying the contents, but I'm looking for general access to the built-in Excel undo operation.

Answer (score 2):

This (and many other missing Excel features) can be access via the api object, like so:

```py
myapp.api.Undo()
# myapp is your app object, e.g., xw.Book("...").app
```

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.undo
- https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/missing_features.html

(Thanks to Felix Zumstein for the [quick response](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/2377#issuecomment-1887492844).)